# A problem concerning action via automorphisms

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

This problem asks to show that if $A$ acts on $G$ via automorphisms, where either $A$ or $G$ is soluble and both $A$ and $G$ are finite groups and $G$ is nontrivial, then $G$ possesses an $A$-invariant $p$-subgroup.

My original attempt at a solution was this:

If $G$ is soluble, then $F(G)>1$, in which case any nontrivial Sylow subgroup of $F(G)$, being characteristic all the way up to $G$, will do the trick.

If $A$ is soluble, choose as above some Sylow $p$-subgroup of $F(A)$, say $P$. Certainly $P$ is normal in $A$ and my claim here is that there exists some $P$-invariant Sylow $q$-subgroup of G, regardless of the condition that $p$ divides $|G|$ or not. If $p$ does not divide $|G|$, then a direct appeal to the extended version of the Sylow theorems for coprime actions proves the claim. If $p$ divides $|G|$, then consider the action of $P$ on $Ω = Syl_p(G)$, which is nonempty. Then $|Ω| =$ sum of $P$-orbits, each a $p$-power, while $|Ω| = 1 (mod p)$. Some $P$-orbit must therefore be a singleton set, meaning that $P$ fixes this particular Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Thus, in all cases the claim holds.

Now suppose that the $P$-invariant Sylow subgroup of $G$ is $Q$, where it's possible that $p$ divides $|Q|$. Then for any $u \in P$ and $a \in A$, $aua^{-1} \in P$. Hence $aua^{-1}(Q)=Q$, implying that $a(Q)Qa^{-1}(Q)=Q$. Thus $a(Q)$ is a subgroup of $N_G(Q)$ and also a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$, because $a$ (being an automorphism) maps Sylow subgroups to Sylow subgroups. Therefore $a(Q)$ is a member of $Syl_q(N_G(Q))$, the sole member of which is $Q$. Finally $a(Q)=Q$ for all $a \in A$ and we are done.

The last paragraph contains an error, but I'm not sure what that is. I haven't used anywhere that $P>1$. But if $P$ is trivial, then $Q$ can be an arbitrary Sylow subgroup of $G$, and of course, $Q$ is not necessarily fixed by $A$.

Comment: Is $aua^{-1}(Q) = a(u(a^{-1}(Q)))$ rather than $a(Q)u(Q)a^{-1}(Q)$?  That would not imply $a(Q) \leq N_G(Q)$, I believe, and explain the problem.  In particular, $a(1(a^{-1}(Q)))= a(a^{-1}(Q))=Q$ for all $a$, regardless of whether $a(Q)$ normalizes anything.

Comment: Right. Thanks for this. Can you suggest a way to deal with the case where $A$ is soluble?

Comment: Today is a little crazy, but I think a full proof is in Kurzweil-Stellmacher, which I believed used similar language and lemmas.  In fact it is so similar in my fuzzy memory, I worry that you are already using that book and somehow it is an exercise.  I'll start writing up a solution, but I suspect it'll be tomorrow before I'm done.

Comment: And by invariant p-subgroup, we mean non-identity invariant p-subgroup of course.

Answer (score 3):

You have covered the case that $G$ is solvable.

If $A$ is solvable, let $P\lhd A$ be a nontrivial $p$-subgroup of $A$, and consider $C_G(P)$, the fixed points of $P$ acting on $G$.  Since for all $x\in P$ and $a\in A$, we have $x^a\in P$, it's not hard to see $C_G(P)$ is $A$-invariant.  Applying induction on $|G|$ then reduces to the case of $C_G(P)=\lbrace1\rbrace$.

Since $|G|\equiv |C_G(P)|\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ in this case, we have that $|G|$ and $|P|$ are coprime, and thus for every prime $q$ dividing $|G|$, there is a unique Sylow $q$-subgroup $Q$ of $G$ which is $P$-invariant (this is theorem 3.23 in *FGT*).  Again, because for all $x\in P$ and $a\in A$, we have $x^a\in P$, it follows that $Q$ is actually $A$-invariant.

Comment: I don't see much difference between your argument and mine. Can you elaborate on your last sentence?

Comment: The difference is saying $(Q)x^a=Q$ is not the same as saying $(Q)a^{-1}Q(Q)a=Q$.  Let $T=(Q)a^{-1}$.  Note that if $T\neq Q$, then $(T)x\neq T$ by uniqueness, and thus $(T)xa\neq Q$, contradicting the fact $x^a\in P$.

Comment: Also the case $C_G(P)=\lbrace1\rbrace$ eliminates the case $P$ is trivial, which was a problem with your argument.

Comment: Since $C_G(P)$ is $A$-invariant, an inductive argument works if $C_G(P)$ is a strict subgroup of $G$, taking into account the special treatment required when $C_G(P)$ is trivial. What if $P$ acts trivially on $G$?

Comment: How many automorphisms do you know that act trivially on their group? :)

Comment: What do you mean? I'm saying, if $P$ fixes every element of $G$, in other words $C_G(P)=G$, then no inductive hypothesis applies.

Comment: @StefanosA: If $C_G(P)=G$, then $P=1$ is not a non-identity subgroup of $A$, contrary to hypothesis.  Steve's argument is a little tricky, since $A$ actually changes during the induction, due to the "WLOG A acts faithfully" being applied multiple times during the induction.

Comment: Why does $C_G(P)=G$ imply $P=1$?

Comment: What kind of automorphism sends each element to itself?

Comment: Also, @JackSchmidt is right, you're gonna want to quotient out $C_A(G)$ when implying induction.

Answer (score 2):

A much stronger claim is false (actually obviously so; I'll not delete in hopes it helps point out why the actual claim should be seen as a generalization of something true):

Let *G* be the alternating group of degree 5, and let *A* be the group of inner automorphisms induced by the alternating group of degree 4.  Let *p* be 3. Then a non-identity *p*-subgroup *P* of *G* has order 3, and is generated by a 3-cycle.  If *A* normalizes the 3-cycle, then the 3-cycle cannot move the point 5, since *P* acts regularly, and so *A* must send the points moved by *P* to points moved by *p*.  Hence *P* is in fact a normal Sylow 3-subgroup of *A*, which does not exist.

In particular, *A* is a finite soluble group of automorphisms acting on the finite group *G*, *p* is a prime, but *G* has no non-identity *A*-invariant *p*-subgroups.

Coprime action would be enough to fix this, and is Kurzweil–Stellmacher's Proposition 8.2.3 on [page 185](http://books.google.com/books?id=6foucBXceC4C&pg=PA185).

Without coprime action every soluble, non-nilpotent group *A* = *G* provides a counterexample, simply because each such group has a non-normal Sylow *p*-subgroup for at least one prime *p*.

However, as Derek Holt points out, surely the problem is just suggesting that there is at least one *p*, not that all *p* work.  This is very similar to Fitting's theorem in the *A* = *G* soluble case: every finite soluble group contains a non-identity normal *p*-subgroup for at least one prime *p*.

Comment: I've got to run.  I think this is right, and asked GAP to verify it, but again today is very rushed, so my apologies in advance if something went wrong.

Comment: I assumed the problem was to show that there is a (presumably nontrivial) $A$-invariant $p$-subgroup for some prime $p$, not necessarily for all primes $p$ dividing $|G|$.

Comment: That sounds much better. Otherwise take g=a solvable but not nil potent.

Comment: I think I might have missed the point of this answer. Surely, the exercise asks for just one prime, not all. Also, it's an exercise from Issac's book, FGT, not Kurzweil-Stellmacher. In particular, it's exercise 3E.1

Comment: You should include the hint then!

Comment: I know there is a hint and I have chosen not to look at it. Why should I include the hint though? Is it somehow misleading not to?

Comment: I will give a solution based on the hint; hopefully you choose to look at it!